# Update using group on Union Incorect Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-server-2014

I need to use group by inside an update

```
Update t1 set t1.TemporaryStock = t1.TemporaryStock + isnull(sum(t2.Quantity),0) 
from inventorymaster t1 join 
(Select * from InventoryTransTemp Union all Select * from InventoryTrans)t2
on t1.InventoryItemID=t2.InventoryItemID where t2.TrnDocumentID=169452 
group by t2.InventoryItemID;
```

I am getting error syntax in group by

If i will use this query with Select instead of update, it works fine
How can i fix group by error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest moving aggregation to the subquery. I also removed the `isnull()` in the outer query, since I do not really see the purpose it serves.

```
update t1 
set t1.TemporaryStock = t1.TemporaryStock + t2.sum_quantity
from inventorymaster t1 
inner join (
    select InventoryItemID, sum(quantity) sum_quantity
    from (
        select InventoryItemID, quantity from InventoryTransTemp where TrnDocumentID = 169452 
        union all Select InventoryItemID, quantity from InventoryTrans where TrnDocumentID = 169452
    ) t
    group by InventoryItemID
) t2 on t1.InventoryItemID = t2.InventoryItemID;
```